# write 0 to disk except existing files

Tags: filesystems, compression, disk

I have an ext4 disk partition. I want to "dd" an image of it. To improve compression ratio of the image, I want to write 0 to all bits not recognized by the filesystem or GPT/MBR. Is this possible and how?

Comment: How, exactly, is this a programming question? Ask on [su]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It is, and if you don't insist on a 100% perfect solution, it is also easy:

Step 1: Unused space on the disk image

- run `fdisk -l` on the image to find out about space on the image, that is not assigned to a partition
- use `dd` to copy from `/dev/zero` to these parts
- On a typical image, this might be so little, as to make skipping this step quite reasonable

Step 2: Unused space in side the file systems

- The output of `fdisk -l` from before gives you enough information to find offset an size to `losetup` a loopdevice to every partition carrying a file system
- For each file system in the image, mount this loop device to a temporary mountpoint
- Now run `dd if=/dev/zero of=/your/mountpoint/zero.fill bs=1M oflag=sync` until it stops with "no space left on device". You can drop the `oflag=sync` for file systems, that do no sparse files.
- Do `rm -f /your/mountpoint/zero.fill` to remove this file

This will leave you with an image, that has zeroed

- **most of** the space not used by a partition
- **most of** the space allocated to a file system, but not used

Answer (score 0):

I don't think thats the way to achieve what you want. Instead, you can compress the file afterward. Better yet,  you can shrink the partition, then dd it, and resize it when you dd it back to a drive. Gparted is the easiest tool for this when working manually.To script it, use the parted, tune2fs and e2fsck tools.